# Is Entity framework only for web applications?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Many tutorials on Entity framework are related to web-based application. But is Entity only for the web?

Can the regular windows based client application, or any other application built using c#.net for that matter, use Entity as an abstraction for DB connectivity?

Comment: It's an ORM. You can use it anywhere you like. If you want something more lightweight look at Dapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework is a very sophisticated ORM (Object Relational Mapper) which allows complex mappings between Database tables and .NET Framework classes.  It is not bound to any specific project type, or even any specific .NET language.  You can use Entity Framework with C#, F#, VB.NET, and even Python, if your library is built correctly.